# Access nested attributes in before save call back

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, callback

I have following relationships

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :applications, :dependent => :destroy 
  before_save: validate_presence_priority_id
end
```

and in my Customer controller I have

```
def customer_params
params.require(:customer).permit(:name, application_attributes: [:duration, :priority_id, :_destroy])
end
```

Now I want to do something like this

```
def validate_presence_priority_id((attributes))
    if !attributes['priority_id'].present?
      attributes.merge!({:_destroy => 1})
    end
end
```

so basically I want to check if `priority_id` is not present then just add destroy attribute. How can I achieve this?